# select2 jquery after replacing Mvc partial view doesn't work any more

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, asp.net-mvc-partialview

My code is placed in a partial view like this:

```html
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserProfileInstance.Employee_Id, new SelectList(Model.EmployeeList, "Id", "FullName"), new { id = "e1" })
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#e1").select2();
      }
</script>
```

First time it works properly, but after its partial view form refresh by Ajax, it load properly again but it is impossible to search, the input box is disabled.
I do not have this problem in multiple select2.

Answer (score 8):

You need to reattach your plugin. The easiest way to do it is to place your plugin init code not only in `$(document).ready()` function but also on [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $("#e1").select2();
});
```

This will init your plugin on the newly added elements to DOM after it added from ajax.

But be careful if you have another ajax call on your View. In that case, you should place your init code in `success` callback of you refresh partial view call.

Comment: the $(document).ready() was in partial view,mean the plugin,was initiated after Ajax while i tried your suggestion too,i put it in $(document).ajaxComplet() although it is initiated ,but i can not  type any thing in search box yet

Comment: @sepideh then can you provide detail in you questio? I mean your ajax call and your partial view

Comment: Thank you this helps still!